# Why is my question about "aboot" locked?

Tags: discussion

[Are Canadianisms like "aboot" equally common on the American side of the border, adjacent to it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/584962/are-canadianisms-like-aboot-equally-common-on-the-american-side-of-the-border)

I understand that people can still answer it, but at first glance it looks like there is some problem with a question (that I'm not seeing).

Comment: **It's only blocking comments**. Maybe there were too many and too distracting. Maybe they contained "answers" and discouraged users from posting answers that can be voted on.

Comment: There are indeed problems with the question, but we can't discuss them.

Comment: Apparently we can now.